# Minimax problem. Stuck in a call stack overflow

Tags: javascript, minimax

Here is the part of the code I think is broken and don't know how to fix:

```
let playerSymbol = '';
let computerSymbol = '';
let computerTurn;
let squareValues = ["x","","","","","","","",""];
 
for (let i=0; i<availableSpots.length; i++) {
        let move = {};
      move.index = newBoard[availableSpots[i]];
      newBoard[availableSpots[i]] = player;
      console.table(newBoard[availableSpots[i]])
      console.table(availableSpots[i])
    //   console.log(newBoard);
    if (player === "x") {
        let result = minimax(newBoard, "o" ,(depth + 1));
        console.log(player,"outside",depth);
        move.score = result.score;
    } else {
        let result = minimax(newBoard, "x", (depth + 1));
        console.log(player,depth,"else")
        move.score = result.score;
        
    }
}
console.log(moves,move)
      newBoard[availableSpots[i]] = move.index;
      moves.push(move);
      console.log(moves,move)
    }
function botPicksSpot() {
        return minimax(squareValues,computerSymbol).index;
    }
    
    function emptySquares() {
        return squareValues.filter(el => el === '').map( (el,index) => index)
    }


const checkGameStatus = (arr, player) => {
    let gameWon = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3) {
        if((arr[i] === arr[i+1]) && (arr[i] === arr[i+2]) && arr[i]) {
            winner = arr[i].toUpperCase();
            endRound()
            if (player === computerSymbol) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return gameWon;
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < (arr.length-6); i++) {
        if((arr[i] === arr[i+3]) && (arr[i] === arr[i+6]) && arr[i]) {
            winner = arr[i].toUpperCase();
            endRound()
            gameWon = {"index": i, "player": player};
            break;  
        }
        return gameWon;
    }
    
    if(((arr[0] === arr[4]) && (arr[0] === arr[8])) && arr[4] || 
    ((arr[2] === arr[4]) && (arr[2] === arr[6]) && arr[4])) {
        winner = arr[4].toUpperCase();
        endRound()
        gameWon = {"index": 4, "player": player};
            return gameWon;
    }
    
    if(winner === '' && !arr.includes('')) {
        winner = 'None';
        endRound();
    }

    if (winner === "" && arr.includes('')) {
        return false;
    }
    return gameWon;
    
}

function assignSymbol() {
    let xOrO = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    // console.log(xOrO);
    if (xOrO === 0) {
        
        // computer starts first;
        computerSymbol = "x";
        playerSymbol = "o";
        // console.log(computerSymbol,playerSymbol)
        computerTurn = true;
        localStorage.setItem("isComputerTurn",computerTurn);
        localStorage.setItem("playerSymbol",playerSymbol);
        localStorage.setItem("computerSymbol",computerSymbol);
        computerMove();
    } else {
;        // player starts first
        computerSymbol = "o"
        playerSymbol = "x";
        // console.log(computerSymbol,playerSymbol)
        computerTurn = false;
        localStorage.setItem("playerSymbol",playerSymbol);
        localStorage.setItem("computerSymbol",computerSymbol);
        localStorage.setItem("isComputerTurn",computerTurn)
    }
}
assignSymbol();

function computerMove() {
       let botIndexPick = botPicksSpot();
    //    console.log(botPicksSpot());
       console.log(squareValues);
        computerTurn = !computerTurn
    }

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
        const gameBoard = document.getElementById("tic-tac-toe-board");

 gameBoard.addEventListener("click", event => {

if (winner !== '' || computerTurn) {
    return; 
} 

let id = event.target.id; // id of "square-0"
if (id.includes("square-")) {
    let gridIndex = parseInt(id[id.length -1])
    if (squareValues[gridIndex] === "") {
        let selectedSquare = document.getElementById(id);
        selectedSquare.innerHTML = 
        `<img src="https://assets.aaonline.io/Module-DOM-API/formative-project-tic-tac-toe/player-${playerSymbol}.svg">`
        squareValues[gridIndex] = playerSymbol;
         }
        } else return;  
        
        localStorage.setItem("savedValues", JSON.stringify(squareValues));
        
        giveUpButton.disabled = false;
        // localStorage.setItem("isComputerTurn",computerTurn)
        whosTurn();
        checkGameStatus(squareValues);
        computerTurn = !computerTurn
        runBotAfterUser();

})
```

It seems to be only updating the first element in the array every time instead of recursively going through the possibly outcomes. What I don't understand is this is basically taken from a project that I was reading about when I started my tic-tac-toe computer vs human project, except that most of my helper functions are structured differently and handle the logic differently.The minimax function is all I took from the other project and its not exactly the same. I did try to change my checkGameStatus function to be more like the example in the tutorial project, but that didn't help. I believe that the newBoard isn't being updated every time it recurses. It just changes the first element of the availableSpots array, everytime. It doesn't select another element in there to change. Which is my confusion because in the project tutorial it worked exactly like how I have it in the for loop.

Thanks for your help and understand

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why not [edit] your post and provide the values for `availableSpots`, `newBoard`, `player`, `minimax`, and `depth`, too? Please see how to create a [mre]. Surely the `console.table` and `console.log` isn’t broken; so, which part is actually broken? Remove everything except that part; include everything necessary to reproduce your issue. _“the first element in the array”_ — which array? _“basically taken from a project that I was reading about”_ — if this is actually relevant, how does that project differ from yours?

Comment: I updated my comment, I'm sorry I'm still new to all this. I provided all the relevant functions, I am not worried about manipulating the HTML at this particular moment, I have that working on a different branch that randomizes the computer choice. I'm strictly worried about putting together the miniMax function right and then I can focus on piecing the parts together

Comment: The code doesn't work at all, have a check with brackets pairs.